# how to put Carousel's Arrow out of the div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Here i applied the Carousel's but arrows are overlapping with images how to reslove this?
I had tried move the arrows using below code:

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
background: none;
color: @red;
border: none;
 }

     .carousel-control.left {margin-left: -45px; color: black;}
     .carousel-control.right {margin-right: -45px; color: black;}
```

but my issue along with images div also slide to -860 width left side and 860 width right side than design looks like images and arrows are overlapping.how to resolve?

Comment: like in this fiddle images are crossing the arrows along with div  http://jsfiddle.net/GcY3V/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to modified the script of carousal like

```
this.options.controls && this._slides.length > 1) {
   carousel.prev('div').find('.controls.left').on('click', function(){
    that._slideTo('prior');
      });
```